# Google GSI Client - How to handle 302 found response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-signin

I'm using gogole sign-in on my Angular application using their [client library](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/client-library).

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
```

In my `AfterViewInit` I use:

```
// @ts-ignore
const acc = google.accounts.id;
acc.initialize()...
```

This works fine in other browsers, but using Edge, I get a `302 found` response with a `Location` header, resulting in ***"google is not defined"*** error.

AFAIK one needs to handle `Location` headers on the client side yourself. Do I need to follow that approach, or is there something else I need to look into?